# how i can running same route in flask At the same time?

Tags: python, flask, apache-kafka

I want to run the same route in Flask.

I want to use flask to get same topic from Kafka and apply different functions.
and After I get the result value, I want to send it to Kafka through another topic.

but it is not working at the same time.

How do we get this to work at the same time?
Is it possible?

Please Help me. :)

```
@app.route('/kafka/') 
def model_a(): 
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092'], 
                                 #client_id = 'name of client', 
                                 auto_offset_reset = 'earliest', 
                                 value_deserializer =\
                                 lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii'))) 
    consumer.subscribe(topics=['numtest']) 
    def events():
        result = []
        for message in consumer:
            if message is not None:
                output = str( message.value["number"]) 
                split_data = [float(i) for i in output.split(",")]
                output = np.round(np.mean(split_data),2)
                producer.flush()
                producer.send('my_topic', {'Result2' : output })
                #yield "<p>Result2 : " + str(output)  +"</p>"
            else :
                producer.flush()
                producer.send('my_topic', {'Result2' : -999 })
                yield "not result : "
                #result.append( str( message.value["number"]) )  # <--- here (str)
            #yield result[0]
    return Response(events()) 

@app.route('/kafka/') 
def model_b(): 
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092'], 
                                 #client_id = 'name of client', 
                                 auto_offset_reset = 'earliest', 
                                 value_deserializer =\
                                 lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii'))) 
    consumer.subscribe(topics=['numtest']) 
    def events():
        result = []
        for message in consumer:
            #print(message)
            #print("result" , message.value["number"])
            if message is not None:
                output = str( message.value["number"]) 
                split_data = [float(i) for i in output.split(",")]
                output = np.round(np.mean(split_data),2)
                producer.flush()
                producer.send('my-topic', {'Result' : output })
                #yield "Result : " + str(output) + "\n"
            else :
                producer.flush()
                producer.send('my-topic', {'Result' : -999 })
                yield "not result : " + "\n"
                #result.append( str( message.value["number"]) )  # <--- here (str)
            #yield result[0]
    return Response(events())
```

Comment: I see no difference between the functions `model_a` and `model_b`. Could you be more specific in what you are asking?

Comment: What I want to do is to have two identical routes working at the same time. Model_a and model_b are arbitrary.
For example, when I do localhost:5000/kafka, you want model_a and model_b to work at the same time.